# including static resource in spring web mvc does not work

Tags: spring-mvc

m not able to get background image in html file. What is wrong in my code?

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbEtk.png)

[controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPz5Q.png)

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqZ7S.png)

[web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QMK3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTATA.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ4yh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/**" mapping="/WEB-INF/"/>
```

in spring-dispatch-servlet.xml file with below code.

```
<mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

create a static folder outside WEB-INF folder in WEB-CONTENT

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"
    cache-period="31556926"/>
```